# Erro na geração da sql com datetime

Tags: php, pdo, php-7

Tenho o seguinte **método**:

```
public function inserir (ClientesModelos $_cliente) : bool {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO clientes (data, nome, sobreNome, nascimento, documento, telefone, celular, email, senha, bloqueio) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';

    $inserir = $this->pdo->prepare ($sql);

    $inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData());
    $inserir->bindValue (2, $_cliente->getNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (3, $_cliente->getSobreNome());
    $inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento());
    $inserir->bindValue (5, $_cliente->getDocumento());
    $inserir->bindValue (6, $_cliente->getTelefone());
    $inserir->bindValue (7, $_cliente->getCelular());
    $inserir->bindValue (8, $_cliente->getEmail());
    $inserir->bindValue (9, $_cliente->getSenha());
    $inserir->bindValue (10, $_cliente->getBloqueio());

    return $inserir->execute();

}
```

Que pede um **objeto** da **classe** *Clientes* e que está sendo gerado como abaixo:

```
$cliente = new ClientesModelos (
         'Carlos',
         'Alberto',
         new DateTime('1970/12/20', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo') ),
         11111111111,
         1111111111,
         11111111111,
         'carcleo@oi.com.br',
         'aaaa',
         'nao' 
);
```

Veja o **print_r**:

```
classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos Object
(
    [idClientes:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => 
    [data:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-09 16:29:25.587117
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
        )

    [nome:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => Carlos
    [sobreNome:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => Alberto
    [nascimento:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 1970-12-20 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
        )

    [documento:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => 11111111111
    [telefone:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => 1111111111
    [celular:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => 11111111111
    [email:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => carcleo@oi.com.br
    [senha:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => aaaa
    [bloqueio:classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesModelos:private] => 1
)
```

Mas quando esse **objeto** entra na **função** *inserir* está dando **erro** na **linha 21** que é:

```
$inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData());
```

E o **erro** é esse:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\mvc\modelos\ClientesDao.php on line 21
```

O que fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta a conversão do Objeto de `Datetime` para `String`, adiciona `->format('Y-m-d')` no `getData()`

```
$inserir->bindValue (1, $_cliente->getData()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

e em Nascimento também

```
$inserir->bindValue (4, $_cliente->getNascimento()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

caso queira adicionar o hora na primeira bind `getData()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: pois é, mas eu gostaria de passar como atributo do objeto new DateTime('1970/12/20', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo') ), lá no objeto. Como faço ? Isso para não mecher lá na classe Dao

Comment: Se é o arquivo `ClientesDao.php` que está errado, é ele que você precisa editar. Ou você altera o arquivo como o Leonardo falou, ou não usa a classe `DateTime`.

Comment: Porque não quer alterar `ClientesDAO`?

Comment: pode deixar, a solução resolve o problema. Boiei aqui, não é possivel enviar objeto php Date|Time ao MySQL